# In C++ Core Guidelines Per.4, why is the bad example intended to be faster?

Tags: c++, performance, cpp-core-guidelines

I am reading [this](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#per4-dont-assume-that-complicated-code-is-necessarily-faster-than-simple-code) recently, which states:

> **Don’t assume that complicated code is necessarily faster than simple code.**

The code is copied as following:

**Example, good**

```cpp
// clear expression of intent, fast execution

vector<uint8_t> v(100000);

for (auto& c : v)
    c = ~c;
```

**Example, bad**

```cpp
// intended to be faster, but is often slower

vector<uint8_t> v(100000);

for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i += sizeof(uint64_t)) {
    uint64_t& quad_word = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&v[i]);
    quad_word = ~quad_word;
}
```

I am not sure what the purpose of the bad example is, why is it **intended to be faster**?
And why is it **in fact often slower**?

Comment: That's interesting.  With no optimization flags the simple one is 10 times slower than the complex one and at -O3 the complex one is slower.  So it depends on the compiler and the flags.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah it's not interesting at all. Measuring the performance of code compiled without optimization on is nonsensical.

Comment: @bolov Maybe not interesting to you.  The fact that the compiler can't optimize the complex one as much as the simple one is interesting to me.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah it can. But with no optimization flags you are "asking" it to not optimize.

Comment: @bolov But the compiler doesn't optimize the complex one as much because it is slower when optimization is turned on.  I would have expected the optimizer to make both come out the same.  It's interesting that it can't do that.

Comment: Also, let's not forget that this `reinterpret_cast` might be a UB. You cannot cast T1 to T2 unless either of them is `(unsigned) char` or `std::byte`. If `uint8_t` happens to be `unsigned char` then we are fine. I would expect that UB allows for better optimizations though.

Comment: @Mikhail Undefined behaviour does not always lead to better performance. Here the problem is that in the second example it is made difficult/tricky for the compiler to identify the optimisations it can perform in terms of using SIMD instructions.

One of the comments to the marked-answer for this question and the second answer to this question, provide more details about this.

Comment: @RishitChaudhary Thanks for your comment. I have changed my mind and remarked Alex Guteniev's answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers would attempt to vectorize operations by performing multiple operations at once using SIMD instructions (SSE/AVX on x86-64, others on other platforms).

By vectoring manually using `uint64_t` you make the compiler performing 8 operations at once, which you see as an improvement in debug build, but may prevent it from making more operations at once (for example, 16 with SSE2, 32 with AVX2, 64 with AVX512), which you see as being slower in release.

Answer (score 5):

By casting the pointer to a 64-bit integer and doing the bitwise operation on that integer, you reduce the number of operations that the C++ code performs by a factor of 8. That is, the assumption being made is that performance is governed by the number of operations written in the C++ code.

Comment: And the bad thing is (I guess) that compiler would easily vectorize the byte loop, but may have troubles with `reinterpret_cast`, especially if `v` is not 8-byte aligned